# Is there a built in way to throw if a COM interface call fails?

Tags: visual-c++, com

At the moment I am using this method for verifying success when using COM interface in my C++ files:

```
inline void CMSATools::throw_if_fail(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        throw _com_error(hr);
    }
}
```

And then use it, something like:

```
throw_if_fail(m_pInterface->SetCongregationDatabasePath(bstrText, &iResult));
```

Is there a built-in mechanism for this that I can use (instead of `throw_if_fail`)?

Comment: It's not built in Windows, but Microsoft provides some (open source) tooling: WRL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl?view=msvc-170), WIL (https://github.com/microsoft/wil) and the latest C++/WinRT, for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/check-hresult and with Visual Studio (ATL) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/debugging-and-error-reporting-global-functions?view=msvc-170#atlthrow